# The "more" link does not direct to the page

Tags: navigation

I am very new at using Drupal some of the answers I see here seem to be the solution but I don't understand the terminology, so if some could explain in simple terms step by step I would be grateful. The problem is that I create a press release which appears on the front page as expected together with a "more" link, however, this does not direct one to the actual article but back to the page I am already on. Please if someone could help me and guide me through the procedure to fix this I would be very happy. Ian

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) At present form of Question it's difficult to answer your question with out more details. Please explain how your press release is getting displayed on home page .. Using views ? Blocks ? Promoted to Front page ? Please include screenshot and give us link of "more" link to investigate further.. Otherwise your question will be closed as "Unclear what you are asking"

Answer (score 0):

I guess what's been bothering you is the "preview" of you nodes.

First, by default, your new "content" ( i guess you are using articles) are promoted to the front page, but that's not where you can find all of them, especially the older ones. It's works like a "latest news" page.

Second, those articles are shown as a "preview", only the first few lines of its content can be read. The "more" link send to the full content of your article.

This link appears even if the article is short enough to be completely read in preview mode, because, only inside the page with the full content you can, for example, add comments etc... etc...

Maybe you didn't notice this because right now the articles you are writing for testing purpose are just too short